# How to resize storyboard? ios

Tags: ios, storyboard, cell

I have more than 10 static table view cells in my app. How can I drag and drop it to storyboard? I can see only 7 of them, Its scrolling on simulator^ but not in storyboard

Comment: it will not scroll in storyboard

Comment: so mayby I can resize down view in storyboard?

Comment: Increase UITableView Height to 1000 and set y of UItableView to some minus value like -100 or -300.

Answer (score 0):

tables dont scroll on storyboards or in the .xib files ,u just have to set the scrolling to yes and then u see it scrolling in simulator or devices

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very common in UIScrollView when Scroll content increase view Size.

There is no inbuilt solution like increase size of ViewController.

But we can have intermediate solution which can help us. Do following.

1. Increase size of UIScrollView or UITableView such that it cover all content. something like 1000 or 1500.
2. set Y to some minus value (like -100 or -300) so your control goes upside and you can see content at down side.

You have to set your Y according to which content you want to see.

Don't forget to change height back to original value after you finish work.