# Xcode Storyboard Scrolling

Tags: xcode

is there a simple way in xcode storyboard to create a scrolling page including both text and images? Also, is this possible without using code? (Code is fine, but preferably none)

Comment: You mean a [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Comment: Simple answer is YES. This link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873861/how-to-resize-storyboard-ios/17874185#17874185

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple but kind of impossible without coding although the code is very simple, just copy and paste this and you should be away.

***This is for your ViewController .h***

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController    

{

IBOutlet UIScrollView *Scroller;

}
```

***This is for your ViewController .m under the super viewdidload***

```
[Scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[Scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
```

Now all you need to do is add your UIScrollView onto your storyboard, in the view Controller scene click view controller, then just look in your outlets and connect them together by dragging from the word Scroller onto your UISCrollview

Comment: Sorry it took a while for me to read the responses, I have been very busy lately. But thank you so much! It worked perfectly! :)

Comment: No worries I'm glad I could help! Any other problems just contact me :)